# SQL Server : AdventureWorks Need HELP! Select Customers where order date is

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I'm working with the `AdventureWorks2017` database.

I need to select `customerID`, `year`, and `ordersQTY` for clients that ordered in 2011 and 2014, but not in 2012 or 2013.

I've tried to code it with where clause but it doesn't seem to work right...

```
WITH SalesQTY AS
(
    SELECT 
        CustomerID, YEAR(OrderDate) Y
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh
    WHERE 
        YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011, 2014)
)
SELECT CustomerID, Y, COUNT(Y)
FROM SalesQTY s
GROUP BY CustomerID, Y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to do this.

```
SELECT CustomerID, YEAR(OrderDate),COUNT(*)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011, 2014)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh1
                WHERE oh.CustomerID=oh1.CustomerID
                AND YEAR(oh1.OrderDate) IN (2012, 2013)
               )
GROUP BY CustomerID, YEAR(OrderDate)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(OrderDate)) = 2
```

Comment: Oh.. I forget that I can exclude that ;)

Comment: But.. does it select all customers that ordered in 2011 AND 2014? 
I dont need from single year.
I need to get all CustomersID that have orders in that 2 exact Years. 
When i place AND instead of IN it shows nothing...

Comment: i misread that part..added a `having` condition to handle it.